# Discord.JS code wont work?

Tags: discord.js

So im making a myth hunters bot for roblox, and I want to copy all users with a certain rank, but thatch not what I want to do, Im just wondering why this will not work. No errors and no reply

```
  var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {

    case "info":
    let mythUser = message.content.replace("mh>info ", "");
    if (mythUser === "fodloca") {
      var fodLoceEmb = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("User: Fodloca")
      .addField("ID: 663751421", "Description: Hey, I'm Fodloca..")
      .setThumbnail("https://www.roblox.com/outfit-thumbnail/image?userOutfitId=663751421&width=420&height=420&format=png")
      message.channel.send(forLoceEmb);
    }
    break;

  }
```

Comment: Is the code relevant to the question? It seems that code you pasted here just sends a embed. Post the code relevant to the question please

Comment: That is relevant. Its the only bit that does not work.

Comment: try `message.channel.send({embed:forLoceEmb});`

Comment: In your question you dont ever say "embed". You're saying "I want to copy all users with a certain rank".

Comment: Yes, im copying the users in a really long format as I couldn't find the way to get all users with the rank, but that was a weird way to say that the if statement didn't work. I've fixed it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use == not ===

```
  var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {

    case "info":
    let mythUser = message.content.replace("mh>info ", "");
    if (mythUser == "fodloca") {
      var fodLoceEmb = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("User: Fodloca")
      .addField("ID: 663751421", "Description: Hey, I'm Fodloca..")
      .setThumbnail("https://www.roblox.com/outfit-thumbnail/image?userOutfitId=663751421&width=420&height=420&format=png")
      message.channel.send(forLoceEmb);
    }
    break;

  }
```